# FLUTTER 2.5/ DART 2.14.0 CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error while performing a POST request

Tags: flutter, http

Since few months I used the code bellow, but recently I update to the last dart and flutter version and I got an error with it.

This is the error in Android Studio :

'MyHttpOverrides.createHttpClient' ('HttpClient Function(SecurityContext)') isn't a valid override of 'HttpOverrides.createHttpClient' ('HttpClient Function(SecurityContext?)').

Does somebody have met the same problem ? And do you fixed it ?

Thanks in advance.

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}

void main(){
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very late. But it can be helpful for others having the same issue.

Change SecurityContext to nullable:

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}

void main(){
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```